# Kendo UI, Scheduler, "There is no such view"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am trying to set up a KendoUI Scheduler, starting from this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline

Straight off, when I copy the demo code into my environment and run the page, console tells me, "Uncaught Error: There is no such view" on kendo.all.min.js:39

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from version 2014.2.1008 to 2015.3.1020 solved the problem.

Comment: In my case, I have put "Year" in the views configuration object of the scheduler.  As of this writing, only "day", "week" and "month" is supported.